# How to revert changes in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I'm editing code in a server using Vim.
I pressed `J` instead of `j` many times, because CapsLock was enabled.
How can I revert the changes made by `J`s? Pressing `u` says it is the oldest change.

Comment: What does `:set undolevels?` say?

Comment: In Vim, `u` should be able to undo all the way. You might be working with Vi, which only stores the single last change? Or did you save and exit Vim in the meantime?

Comment: did you save the file before exiting or did you just exit?

Answer (score 12):

See the undolevel settings in your session. Type below command to see current undolevels setting.

```
:set undolevels ?
```

You can change the setting either in the session or in .vimrc

```
:set undolevels=1001  # In vi/vim session

set undolevels=1001  # In .vimrc
```

In vi/vim, you can keep pressing <kbd>u</kbd> to undo the changes, based on the undolevels.

In vi/vim, if you want to undo all the changes, since you had last saved, you can do below things.

You can go to command mode by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then give below command

```
:e! or :edit!
```

It will clear all the changes in buffer. The file will return to last saved version.